# Is there a way to modify this code to let spark streaming read from json?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm working on a spark streaming app/code which continuously reads data from localhost 9098. Is there a way to modify localhost into <users/folder/path> so to read data from folder path or json automatically ?

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

object StreamingApplication extends App {

  Logger.getLogger("Org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

  //creating spark streaming context
  val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "wordCount")
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))

  // lines is a Dstream
  val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9098)

  // words is a transformed Dstream
  val words = lines.flatMap(x => x.split(" "))

  // bunch of transformations
  val pairs = words.map(x=> (x,1))
  val wordsCount = pairs.reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)

  // print is an action
  wordsCount.print()

  // start the streaming context
  ssc.start()

ssc.awaitTermination()


}
```

Basically, I need help to modify code below:

```
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9098)
```

to this:

```
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("<folder path>")
```

fyi, I'm using IntelliJ Idea to build this.

Comment: First result from searching for "spark streaming file" is this: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-streaming-read-json-files-from-directory/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading Spark documentation, especially the scaladoc.

There seem to exist a method `fileStream`.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.html

Comment: Tried textFileStream too but somehow it is not working. Am I missing something ?

`val lines = ssc.textFileStream("Users/Desktop/raw.json")`

Comment: It listen for new files in a directory, it doesn't read 1 existing file.

Comment: ok, but is there a way to read data inside the file ?